# No way to transform this Format Date into another Javascript Moment.js

Tags: javascript, format, momentjs

I am using Moment.js to dates, and I need to change one format to another one, and currently is being difficult.

The one I have is this: `2017-09-12T01:11:48+02:00`

And the format I want is like this one: `Thu Oct 05 2017 12:20:00 GMT+0200`

I'm sorry if you think this question is "to avoid the search", but I've  been searching for a long while.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
moment().format('ddd MMM D YYYY, H:mm:ss [GMT]Z')
```

You can find about it right in `moment` documentation. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/